# Как импортировать данные через Python в таблицы с FOREIGN KEY

Tags: python, mysql

Даны две таблицы в mySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE tab1(id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name TEXT 
NOT NULL, surname TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id));

CREATE TABLE tab2(id_meta BIGINT(20) NOT NULL, height INT(7) NOT NULL, 
FOREIGN KEY (id_meta) REFERENCES tab1 (id));
```

Как правильно на Python при импорте данных прописать команду, чтобы данные заполнялись в две таблицы.

Данные a = ["Андрей", "Иванов", "180"]

```
#запись данных в tab1
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('INSERT INTO tab1(name, surname) VALUES (%s, %s)', (a[0], a[1]))

#получаем:
 +------+------+---------+
 |  id  | name | surname | 
 +------+------+---------+
 |   5  |Андрей| Иванов  |
 +------+------+---------+
```

А как заносить данные в tab2 под тем же id_meta что и id в tab1 не пойму, помогите пожалуйста. Должно получиться так:

```
 +---------+--------+
 | id_meta | height |
 +---------+--------+
 |    5    |   180  |
 +---------+--------+
```

Comment: Никто не знает?

Answer (score 3):

Чисто SQL решение:

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO tab1(name, surname) VALUES ('name', 'surname');
INSERT INTO tab2(id_meta, height) VALUES (last_insert_id(), '180');
COMMIT;
```

а вообще.. лучше конечно использовать ORM (sqlalchemy например)

Comment: Почему именно лучше использовать ORM (sqlalchemy например)? можно про него подробнее, пожалуйста.

Comment: @ChikChirik почитайте о том что такое ORM. Если в общем он позволяет на много удобнее работать с базой данные, работа с базой приводится к работе с обьектами, не нужно писать SQL запросы в обычном виде, и проблем с вот такими операциями тоже не будет, это всё автоматизируется. Но всё же, если вы только начинаете учить программирование - то пока поработайте так, а на будущее - стоит учить sqlalchemy

Comment: cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('INSERT INTO tab1(name, surname) VALUES (%s, %s)', (a[0], a[1]))   cur.execute('INSERT INTO tab2(height) VALUES (last_insert_id(), '180')') Ошибка получается

Comment: не знаете почему ошибка?

Comment: tab2(id_meta, height) тогда уж надо писать, поскольку вставляется же два значения, для обоих надо поля указать

Answer (score 2):

Id вставленной записи для вставки в новую таблицу в качестве id_meta можно взять из **cur.lastrowid** либо из **conn.insert_id()**, как сказано в этом ответе: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2548531/8324991

Comment: Спасибо большое)